# Erlang freezes on supervisor:start_child

Tags: erlang

I want to start a supervisor with a process that would spawn more processes linked to the supervisor. The program freezes at `supervisor:start_child`.

The supervisor starts the main child:

```
% supervisor (only part shown)

init([]) ->
    MainApp = ?CHILD_ARG(mainapp, worker, [self()]),
    {ok, { {one_for_one, 5, 10}, [MainApp]} }.
```

The main child starts here:

```
% mainapp (gen_server)

start_link([SuperPid]) when is_pid(SuperPid) ->
    io:format("Mainapp started~n"),
    gen_server:start_link({local, ?MODULE}, ?MODULE, [SuperPid], []).

init([SuperPid]) ->
    {ok, _Pid} = start_child(childapp, SuperPid),   % <-- here start the other
    {ok, #state{sup=SuperPid}}.

start_child(Module, SuperPid) ->                             % Module = childapp
    io:format("start child before~n"),                       % printed
    ChildSpec = ?CHILD(Module, worker),
    {ok, Pid} = supervisor:start_child(SuperPid, ChildSpec), % <-- here freezes
    io:format("start child after~n"),                        % not printed
    {ok, Pid}.
```

And the other child source contains

```
% childapp

start_link([]) ->
    io:format("Child started~n"),
    gen_server:start_link({local, ?MODULE}, ?MODULE, [], []).

%% gen_server interface

init([]) ->
    {ok, #state{}}.
```

What I get at the output when running the app is:

```
erl -pa ebin -eval "application:start(mysuptest)"
Erlang R16B01 (erts-5.10.2) [source-bdf5300] [smp:2:2] [async-threads:10] [hipe] [kernel-poll:false]

Eshell V5.10.2  (abort with ^G)
1> Mainapp started
start child before
```

and here it stops - it freezes, and does not return to the erlang console as usual. I do not get any error caught or any other messages. Any ideas? Do I start the child properly?

Comment: what happens if you do not call `mainapp:start_child` from inside `mainapp:init`, but do it manually from the shell prompt once the `supervisor` and `mainapp` have started? I am new to Erlang, but I suspect that it happens because `gen_server:start_link` is synchronous, and while it is running, `gen_server` is not receiving messages. I think that `supervisor:start_child` is a call that is converted into a message that is sent to the supervisor. Please see the documentation for `gen_server`, there it says that `call` is synchronous. But I am not sure about all of this because I am new to this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you start a child process, the call from supervisor will return only after the child process init (in case the child process is a gen_server the start_link gets blocked till init) is returned. You are starting the main gen_server in the supervisor. Hence the supervisor is waiting for the mainapp to return. Meanwhile the mainapp is calling supervisor:start_child function. This gets blocked because the supervisor is waiting for return from mainapp. This results in a deadlock situation.

One possible solutions is that do not call start_child in the mainapp and do it asynchronously after init returns

For this you can send a cast message to itself where you can start the child. Or you can spawn another process which starts and sends the response (child Pid) to the mainapp

```
init([SuperPid]) ->
    handle_cast(self(), {start, SuperPid}),   % <-- send a cast message to itself
    {ok, #state{sup=SuperPid}}.
```

Another preferred solution is having a supervision tree. The child process can have its own supervisor and the mainapp calls the child's supervisor to start the child process.

Comment: In the latter case, the second supervisor (this one for the children processes) should be also started dynamically by the `mainapp`?

Comment: both mainapp and the child process supervisor can be started by the application supervisor. [example](http://learnyousomeerlang.com/building-applications-with-otp#a-pools-tree)